# Image is not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive, srcset

I'm trying to show different images on different screen size. If I resize the window, disable cache and refresh it's ok, but when I choose device to view the result in specific screen resolution the images are not showed properly. When the device is iPad (768x1024) - image 1170x425 is showing, iPhone (375x667) - image 768x480 is showing. The image for mobile is not loading. What I'm doing wrong ?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <img srcset="https://i.imgur.com/NM5jNhl.jpg 400w,
                 https://i.imgur.com/PIHmZC1.jpg 768w,
                 https://i.imgur.com/FqVHaE4.jpg 1170w"
         sizes="100vw" src="https://i.imgur.com/FqVHaE4.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nnc3j5n3/3/ looks like it is working

Comment: It's working when resize, but if you are on real device it's not.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the ipad is 768px wide? As in does the background colour change to red? I am testing on simulator iPad pro 9.7 inch, iOS 10.2 the width of the browser is coming up as 770px

Comment: On iPhone the small image is showing ?

Comment: Which one is the small image? and which iPhone?

Comment: this one - https://i.imgur.com/NM5jNhl.jpg, (400x400) iPhone - 5 and 7

Comment: I don't know the width of iphone 7 but iphone 5 it is 320px and in your code, you define width 400w or below use 400x400 so what's the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165667/discussion-between-xaos-and-huangism).

Answer (score 1):

You should define your sizes:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="image-800w.jpg">
```